# Rails 3 rendering template missing without file ending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an action in my controller as below:

```
 def show
    @post = Post.find_by_setitle(params[:setitle])

    if !@post
      render 'error_pages/404'
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

If the `render error_pages/404` I get a template missing. Switching it to `render error_pages/404.haml.html` works fine.

Why is this?

N.B. There is no actual error_pages controller or model. Just a convenient place to keep them.

Edit: I'm using mongoid and hence don't have access to ActiveRecord. Controller base can't be looking for a particular ActiveRecord exception?

Comment: What do you mean `Switching it to render error_pages/404.haml.html` ?

Comment: @Zabba - Literally changing the line to `render 'error/pages/404.haml.html'`

Comment: Maybe you meant to have some words after that sentence, I meant. Also what is the template error (along with all the context)? And in which directory is the `error_pages` directory in?

Comment: @Zabba `error_pages` folder is in `app/views/`

Comment: Check if the view template exists in the paths that the missing template error shows (`Missing template ... in view paths ...`)

Comment: @Zabba - It is looking in `app/views` but doesn't look in the error_pages folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

> The render method can also use a view that’s entirely outside of your application (perhaps you’re sharing views between two Rails applications):
>
> Rails determines that this is a file render because of the leading slash character. To be explicit, you can use the :file option (which was required on Rails 2.2 and earlier):

You need either to pass the `:file` option, or to start the location string with a slash. Alternatively, you could use the Rails functionality to rescue from errors, and recover from  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` with a 404. See [this post](http://www.treyconnell.com/automatically-raise-recordnotfound-exceptions-rails) for details.

Comment: I don't have active record - but controller can't be looking for a particular ActiveRecord exception can it? Seems a little tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `render :template => 'error_pages/404'`. 
I think Rails is looking for a partial called `_404`.

Try it out 1:

`render 'error_pages/404'` (and name the file `_404.html.erb`)

Try it out 2:

`render :template => 'error_pages/404'` (and name the file `404.html.erb` i.e. no leading underscore)